# Using Mailgun with Craft

Tags: emails

Is it possible to use the Mailgun SDK with Craft at this point?

If not, is it OK to just the composer autoloader as a second autoloader (I'm about to test it, I'm just curious whether it's kosher or there's a different way of doing it that doesn't involve writing another plugin)?

Comment: Just FYI: requiring vendor/autoload.php (from my plugin) worked and correctly loads Mailgun. So I guess it works, it's just (more than a little) ugly

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you 100%, but seems like you should just need to load up Craft's `craft\app\bootstrap.php` file and run with it.  Regardless, can you add your solution as an official answer to the question?

Answer (score 4):

The asker was able to solve their question and confirm that MailGun can be used with Craft. In the comment they state:

> Just FYI: requiring vendor/autoload.php (from my plugin) worked and
>   correctly loads Mailgun. So I guess it works, it's just (more than a
>   little) ugly

We have had success integrating Craft with MailGun in our plugins as well.  While we have not released our integration publicly, we have a [Sprout Email](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email) MailGun integration used by our direct customers and we were able to successfully integrate with Email Lists and Campaigns, and allow users to build Emails using Craft templates with Live Preview and send them through the MailGun API.